# Zero-day malware protection

Tags: malware, firewalls, antimalware

What is the best approach in defending your company against zero-day malware?

Is there a firewall/system to do that?

Is it good to run every file in a sandbox and to track activity of the sandbox?

Comment: Rephrase: **it depends** on who within a company is asking and what business that company does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't defend from a threat effectively, which you don't know yet.

0-day vulnerability is a threat  which you don't know yet.

See [HeartBleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) for example.

But [this paper](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/bestprac/defenses-zero-day-exploits-various-sized-organizations-35562) discusses how to minimize risk against 0-days.

And this is the conclusion part from the paper:

> Most of the defense techniques available to organizations today are
>   available in  off
>   - the
>   - shelf hardware and software applications. The methods used by hardware and  software applications are usual ly defined as a hybrid
>   model. In order to best defend  against zero
>   - day exploits, an organization needs to understand what defense techniques  their defense in depth strategy defends against. The
>   ability for a smaller organization to  defend itself versus a l arge
>   organization is often limited by knowledge of the threat by IT  staff
>   and senior management, as well as limited financial resources. The
>   amount of  information available to users and management is growing
>   daily. Through organizations  like SANS, security journals, and media
>   outlets , organizations can benefit by educating  decision makers on 
>   zero
>   - day explo i t risks and defense approaches so that informed action  can be taken to minimize the possible impact in the future .

Comment: I know I am searching for a gold mine but I am thinking in sandbox everything to minimize risk.

Comment: I checked you idea, and found some paper about this. There is no efficient way to prevent it, but if you have enough money and time(big companies), you can reduce the risk. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are very few effective ways of detecting 0day malware. Some of the things you can do to minimize risk is reduce the attack surface as much as possible (don't run unnecessary services) and use scanning engines with heuristics.

To be honest, they are unlikely to pick up anything much past the most basic obfuscated / fresh malware but there is little else you can do.

Comment: Are there any other solution? (even if I lose a lot of performance to gain a bit more security)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a firewall/system to do that?

There are some which will help but none is 100% effective.

> Is it good to run every file in a sandbox and to track activity of the sandbox?

This will help and this is what most APT (advanced persistent threat) solutions do, but it will not help fully. Malware often detects when it is running inside a sandbox and behave differently.

> What is the best approach in defending your company against zero-day malware?

- Limit what you get by white listing instead of black listing whenever possible (i.e. sites and file types allowed instead of allowing everything which is not forbidden).
- Limit spreading of malware by isolation at the application level (sandbox etc),  the network level and with access lists.
- Assume that you are hacked and look for indicators (breach detection).
- Train your staff.
- Read about the typical attacks, learn how the attacks worked and learn how to protect against such attacks.
- Spend a lot of money on either in-house intelligence or let you systems manage by others.

Security can definitely be costly so you have to find the right balance between what are the assets worth you want to protect and how much you can afford on security products and on reduced productivity caused by limiting access lists etc. And, don't believe the marketing claims of a single vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I see this question was been way too broad to answer. However, I'll make some assumptions of that your running Windows on x86/x64 and you're protecting native executables not byte code languages such as Java, .NET and so on.

Short answer: No, you can't protect yourself from zero-day. You're protecting from an attack which isn't yet known.

Long answer: You can minimalise the potential chance of a zero day exploit happening and/or the scope of the attack.

The things you can do to prevent the attack:

1. If you're the developer of the software, you can enable ASLR for your application.
2. You can enable DEP

The things you can do to reduce the scope:

1. Run the application minimum requirement as required. For example, if the application doesn't need administrator rights etc. Run it as standard user.
2. Firewall rules for an application. For example, if your running an website. You'll only require TCP 80 and TCP 443. So, filter much port as you can and IPs if there is only an known set of IPs.
3. AntiVirus configure the access rights your application has. If it doesn't need write access to your documents, then ensure it's denied.
4. Sandbox for more coverage which has advantage of simulating what actually has happened rather than the AV denying the permissions.

If you share more on exactly what you're looking for, I'll able to expand my answer.

[Address space layout randomization (ASLR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

[Data Execution Prevention (DEP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection)